# Bypassing a validation decorator in pytest for flask endpoint

Tags: flask, pytest, python-decorators

I've been trying to bypass a validation decorator which is on a flask endpoint so I can unit test the endpoint without worrying about the decorator.

```
def auth_required(roles):
    def wrapper(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def decorator(*args, **kwargs):
           # logic here just checks roles in jwt token in auth header
           return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorator
    return wrapper
```

Then I have an endpoint in a blueprint like this:

```
@organisationcontroller.route('/organisations', methods=['GET'])
@auth_required(['admin'])
def get_organisations():
    organisations = org_service.get_all()
    return {"organisations": [org.__dict__ for org in organisations]}
```

and a simple test case would just confirm that a 200 response is returned I guess

```
def test_organisations_happy_path(app_client):
    # Call the endpoint without the decorator
    response = app_client.get('/organisations')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

Of course, this test will try to invoke the auth_required decorator and will fail. I don't really want to be testing decorator logic when I run this test, it should just test the endpoint.

I've tried various approaches, such as the one described here:
https://pythonin1minute.com/how-to-test-decorators-in-python/

by changing my test to:

```
def test_organisations_happy_path(app_client):
    # Call the endpoint without the decorator
    response = app_client.get('/organisations').__wrapped__()
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

But this throws an error of WrapperTestResponse has no attribute wrapped... I think this is because **wrapped** is coming from the route decorator, not the auth_decorator.

I've also tried patching the decorator prior to import but I can't get that to work either.

I've also tried writing a mock decorator and replacing the decorator from within the test, also not working.

Surely I'm not the first to need to do this. The other threads I found on stack do not seem to deal with bypassing decorators that are applied to an endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a way to make it work. It's pretty hacky though .

```
def test_organisations_happy_path(app, app_client):
    view_function_name = 'get_organisations'
    view_function = app.view_functions[view_function_name]
    app.view_functions[view_function_name] = view_function.__wrapped__
    response = app_client.get('/organisations')
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

So the idea is to use a Flask app fixture to modify your `get_organisations` view function before you perform a request to `/organisations`.

The approach you tried doesn't work because when you run `app_client.get('/organisations')` it's already too late: Your view function is run when you run `app_client.get('/organisations')` so your `auth_required` decorator code will run also.

Now most of the time in situations like these I just like to create a function that is called inside the route and test that function. I find that sufficient in most situations and it's nice and simple.

Comment: Thanks so much! I was on this for ages. For any one in the future, note that if you're using a blueprint then view_function_name includes the blueprint. i.e. 
view_function_name = 'organisationcontroller.get_organisations'